# Invalid command 'location', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: php, url-rewriting, apache2

Currently, I am setting my local environment for a project.

Project runs on production environment with nginx server. But in the local development, using apache server. I've installed LAMP stack on my ubuntu machine. There is already a virtual host file provided and I have setup it. So far I've created `xxx.conf` file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

The file includes:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
 ServerName xxx     
 DocumentRoot /home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public

 <Directory "/home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public">            
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI            
    AllowOverride all            
    Require all granted        
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx-error.log        
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx-access.log combined        
 SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also created .htaccess file under `/home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public`. The content of this file downloaded from production environment.

The content of `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
location ~ ^/site { rewrite ^/site(.*)$ https://local.xxx.com/$1 redirect;}
```

So, when I type `local.xxx.com` in browser, it gives 500 Internal Error.

So, I was defined `xxx-error.log` in virtual host config file. I've opened it. The content is:

```
[Tue May 28 22:23:33.231851 2019] [core:alert] [pid 5677] [client 127.0.0.1:56504] /home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
[Tue May 28 22:23:33.254608 2019] [core:alert] [pid 5678] [client 127.0.0.1:56506] /home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public/.htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context, referer: http://local.xxx.com/
[Tue May 28 22:33:22.300863 2019] [core:alert] [pid 6326] [client 127.0.0.1:56740] /home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'location', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Tue May 28 22:33:22.317420 2019] [core:alert] [pid 6327] [client 127.0.0.1:56742] /home/ubuntuser/Downloads/xxx-master/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'location', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://local.xxx.com/
```

So, I understand there is problem in the `.htaccess` but i don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using apache and in your .htaccess  using the convention of Nginx.

Refer to latest documentation of apache2.4

To me it seems like you want to redirect use this

`RewriteRule ^/site(.*)$ https://local.xxx.com/$1` or maybe this

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`